# Using BeforeClose and ActiveX CheckBox values in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, activex

I am trying to prevent an excel workbook from closing based-on the state of a checkbox.

My sample code that is placed in 'ThisWorkbook' :

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If CheckBox0.Value = "FALSE" Then
    b = MsgBox("Are you sure that you want to submit?", vbYesNo)
    End If
    If b = vbNo Then Cancel = True

End Sub
```

At the moment, I am getting a run-time error 424 , object required and the debug points at the If `CheckBox0.Value.....` line.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and I'm not a regular VBA user.

Help, please.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using an embedded Checkbox (ActiveX). If so, you need to specify the sheet that the checkbox lives in. You can't just say `Checkbox0` because you can have `Checkbox0` on multiple sheets.

The other thing is that you can't check for `"False"` because it's not a string, but a boolean value, so you can just use `False` because that is an inherent VBA keyword.

Here's what I think you're looking for:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim b As Long
    If (Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value = False) Then
        b = MsgBox("Are you sure that you want to submit?", vbYesNo)
    End If

    If b = vbNo Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention to switch `"Sheet1"` for the sheet name that your checkbox lives in.